# Working with Twitter API v1.1

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I launched this code via terminal via command `python py/twi.py` and it shows no reaction:

```
import oauth, tweepy
from time import sleep    

message = "hello"

def init():
    global api
    #confident information
    consumer_key = "***"
    consumer_secret = "***"
    callback_url = "https://twitter.com/Problem196"
    access_key="***"
    access_secret="***"
    auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret, callback_url)
    auth.set_access_token(access_key, access_secret)
    api=tweepy.API(auth)

init()
api.update_status(message)
```

But it supposed to post tweet "hello" on page https://twitter.com/problem196 .
I have updated tweepy, it's fine. Why it's not posting? I have no idea. Please help.
UPD: After I put code `print api.last_response.msg` terminal showed me some errors:

```
artem@artem-VirtualBox:~$ python py/twi.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "py/twi.py", line 20, in <module>
    api.update_status(message)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tweepy-2.1-py2.7.egg/tweepy/binder.py", line 197, in _call
    return method.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tweepy-2.1-py2.7.egg/tweepy/binder.py", line 154, in execute
    raise TweepError('Failed to send request: %s' % e)
tweepy.error.TweepError: Failed to send request: [Errno -2] Name or service not known
artem@artem-VirtualBox:~$ python py/twi.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "py/twi.py", line 20, in <module>
    api.update_status(message)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tweepy-2.1-py2.7.egg/tweepy/binder.py", line 197, in _call
    return method.execute()
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tweepy-2.1-py2.7.egg/tweepy/binder.py", line 173, in execute
        raise TweepError(error_msg, resp)
    tweepy.error.TweepError: [{'message': 'Status is a duplicate', 'code': 187}]
```

Comment: What does `print api.last_response.msg` prints if you put it after the last line?

Comment: I writed update for this post.

Comment: Try to add `os.environ['http_proxy']=''` before the `api.update_status(message)` call.

Comment: @ArtemDremov Is this still not working?